# Jenkinsfile multibranch deploy on merge to branch

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup a conditional in a multibranch pipeline, defined via a Jenkinsfile.

I am really struggling to find good documentation on the when clause, and my specific use, which seems fairly common.

I would like to:

Trigger a deploy when a PR is merged into our dev branch. It is important that this job only run in this specific situation, so multiple deploy jobs don't go in at once.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://devopscube.com/jenkins-build-trigger-github-pull-request/

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I am looking for this in the context of a Jenkinsfile, and not manual job configuration